# Preloading Files

Tags: cache, tmpfs, preload

I want to pre-load some Files / Programs into the memory, ram, cache to open / access them faster.

I already tried creating a tmpfs, ramfs System
https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/RAM-Disk_erstellen
(Sorry its in German) by calling those commands for Example

```
sudo mount -t ramfs ramfs /media/ramdisk 
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=20% none /media/ramdisk
```

and put some data (arround 1GiB) in it.

I also tried pre-loading the Files directly 
[Mount /usr in RAM (loading from HDD when starting, and saving to when shutting down)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135734/mount-usr-in-ram-loading-from-hdd-when-starting-and-saving-to-when-shutting-d/135737#135737?newreg=99a9ec378f1b44df923bdc955c624c53) (top answer)

```
cat /bin/* /lib/* /usr/bin/* /usr/lib/* >/dev/null
```

or

```
ionice -c 3 find /bin /usr/bin /usr/lib* -type f -exec ionice -c 3 cat '{}' ';' > /dev/null &
```

but regardless what I’m doing I see no Ram Change via System Monitor / htop

Its always around 1,7GiB / 3,8GiB
I’m running Lubuntu 14.10

Do you know of any limitations for doing so running a Ubuntu System or is there something else to do to archive what I want or am I missing some other important Point?

Comment: Run `free -h` for detailed data about RAM usage. Notice the "cached" collumn

Comment: Here's the Output:
3,8G [total]      3,6G [used]  1,5G [cached]

But why is "free" showing other values than htop?

Comment: Just googled it by my self
http://askubuntu.com/questions/369466/memory-usage-statistics-different-in-free-and-htop
So i think you solved my question ^^
The only thing left to do for me is to measure the speed improvement now

Comment: and also this is a good reference for this question.... so it is really all about how memory is actually counted... I totally missed that
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176309/tmpfs-creating-file-in-tmpfs-does-not-change-memory-usage-in-htop-top

Comment: Glad you solved it yourself. I recommend using [preload](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/preload/) instead of manually load every libs and binary to RAM. Preload can profile your usage and select binaries and libraries that you often use and load them to RAM automatically

Comment: I've been running preload for a month but could'nt measured big differences..... also thought about using prelink since its more configurable but never tested it so far. do you know about prelink?

Comment: You could read about it from [the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Prelink). HDD and CPU nowadays are fast enough so that differences are negliable. I suggest reading [Maximizing Performance](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Maximizing_performance) if you want to increase your PC performance